# No such test method for python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to `unittest` so I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filemerge_test.py", line 98, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "filemerge_test.py", line 92, in main
    filemerge_test.test_runner()
  File "filemerge_test.py", line 19, in test_runner
    self.addTest(TestFunctionality(self.log, self.options))
  File "/nfsdata/DSCluster/home/bli1/filemerge/tests/testcases.py", line 45, in __init__
    super(TestFunctionality, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'testcases.TestFunctionality'>: runTest
```

Full code is here: http://dpaste.com/0W1GEW6

I think it is because I am not running the tests correctly.

Here is a summary of how my testing is currently written:

```
from testcases import TestFunctionality

class FileMergerTest(unittest.TestSuite)
    def __init__(self, log, options):
        super(FileMergerTest, self).__init__()
        self.options = options
        self.log = log

    def test_runner(self):
        self.addTest(TestFunctionality(self.log, self.options))
        self.run()

def main()
    ...
    ...
    filemerge_test = FileMergerTest(log, options)
    filemerge_test.test_runner()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

In my `testcases.py` where I imported `TestFunctionality`

```
class TestFunctionality(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, log, options):
        super(TestFunctionality, self).__init__()
        self.options = options
        self.log = log
        ...

    def test_outputs(self, test_type)
        ...
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.test_outputs("-d")
        self.test_outputs("-f")
```

I tried adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

At the end of my `testcases.py` file but I got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to [override `runTest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) and not `run`:

```
# def run(self): # <--- remove
def runTest(self): # <--- use this
    self.test_outputs("-d")
    self.test_outputs("-f")
```

As the error suggests.